# How would select() return anything other than -1, 0, or 1?

Tags: c, select, file-descriptor

This is definitely just a dumb misunderstanding on my part, but the man page for select() states:

> The timeout argument specifies the interval that select() should block waiting for a file descriptor to become ready.  The call will block until either:
>
> *a file descriptor becomes ready;
>
> *the call is interrupted by a signal handler; or
>
> *the timeout expires.

And furthermore, that

> On success, select() and pselect() return the number of file
>          descriptors contained in the three returned descriptor sets (that is,
>          the total number of bits that are set in readfds, writefds,
>          exceptfds) which may be zero if the timeout expires before anything
>          interesting happens.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to
>          indicate the error; the file descriptor sets are unmodified, and
>          timeout becomes undefined.

So my question is -- if it stops blocking as soon as a file descriptor is ready, would it not immediately return 1? And if no fds become ready, it returns 0, otherwise error and returns -1.

Obviously in practice it returns more than 1: the whole point is that you should be able to read/write multiple fds, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way modern preemptive multitasking works, multiple descriptors could become ready before your process is awoken and the `select` calls counts the descriptors.